# What may be the reason of false malware alarms on this exe I generate?

Tags: windows, x86, exe, reverse-engineering, portable-executable

my friend who is on windows xp and cant post question
send me a question to post for him:

i wrote an x86 32-bit-windows assembler (named org-asm)

the problem is some antivirs report the output exe as a malware though its really not and i dont know what may be the reason

i loged soem reports from the pe file i generate which i may include here

this given exe is build like that

- first 0x200 bytes is my PE header
- next 0xC00 bytes is my asm code compiled (standard though i use long jumps and longer 32 bit forms of acces etc which some disasembler reports may be optimised)
- next 0x600 bytes is import section (list of imports to dlls, standard)
- next 0x600 bytes is initialised data section (standard)
  and this exe closes (in a exe size of 0x1a00 bytes)

the info from pe file i log is here,
note im not a specialist on pe format i
filled it up on some tutorials i read but im noit sure if i get it right and
possibly maybe i badly initialized some values ?

windows loader reads it ok (though i test it only on 32 bit xp) but some
antivirs of people i send it to reports its potential malware and this is annoying

tnx for help

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Filing PE Header:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Verbose PE header settings:  (all numbers in hex)

 --- sizeof IMAGE_DOS_HEADER  <0040> ---------------

 magic                    <5a4d>
 pe ofset in file         <0080>
 sizeof dos stub[]        <0040>

 --- sizeof IMAGE_NT_HEADERS  <00f8> ---------------

 signature                <4550>

 --- sizeof IMAGE_FILE_HEADER <0014> ---------------

 machine                <014c>
 number of sections     <0003>
 time date stamp        <5e0be100>
 opt. header size set   <00e0>
 characteristics        <0307>

 --- sizeof IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER <00e0> -----------

 major linker           <0002>  minor linker <0000>
 size of code set       <0c00>
 size of init. data set <0600>
 size of unit. data set <0000>
 adres of entry point   <1000>
 base of code           <1000>
 base of data           <3000>
 image base             <400000>
 section aligment       <1000>
 file aligment          <0200>
 major os ver           <0004>  minor os ver  <0000>
 major image ver        <0001>  minor image ver  <0000>
 major subsystem ver    <0004>  minor subsystem ver  <0000>
 win32 version value    <0000>
 size of image          <4000>
 size of headers        <0200>
 checksum               <0000>
 subsystem              <0002>
 size of stack reserve  <200000>  size of stack sommit  <1000>
 size of heap reserve   <100000>  size of heap commit  <1000>
 loader flags           <0000>

 no. of rva and sizes   <0010>
 DD[01] virtual adress  <2000>  DD[01] size  <0480>
 DD[12] virtual adress  <2434>  DD[12] size  <0050>

 --- sizeof IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER <0028> ------------

 sec1 name            .text
 virtual size         <1000>
 virtual sdress       <1000>
 size of raw data     <0c00>
 pointer to raw data  <0200>
 characteristics      <60000020>

 sec2 name            .idata
 virtual size         <1000>
 virtual sdress       <2000>
 size of raw data     <0600>
 pointer to raw data  <0e00>
 characteristics      <40000040>

 sec3 name            .data
 virtual size         <1000>
 virtual sdress       <3000>
 size of raw data     <0600>
 pointer to raw data  <1400>
 characteristics      <c0000040>

 -- offsets in saved file: -------------------------

 dosHeader:               <0000> dos_stub: <0040>
 ntHeader:                <0080> header: <0084> opHeader: <0098>
 sectionheaderCode:       <0178>
 sectionheaderImports:    <01a0>
 sectionheaderData:       <01c8>

 code section file ofset:    <0200> size: <0c00>
 imports section file ofset: <0e00> size: <0600>
 data section file ofset:    <1400> size: <0600>
 file end:                   <19ff>
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Output Saved:  output.exe
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 OK  (assembled in 0.024 s)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Inspect your executable with [PEViewer](http://wjradburn.com/software/) and compare with sane PE files. `IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER.SizeOfRawData` should define the real size of emited code/data, not aligned to FileAlign. Perhaps this looks suspicious to AV software.

Comment: @vitsoft OK, iIcheck in virus total and after this raw data size change aletrs dropped down from 7 to 6 (i got 10 initially but dropped to 7 when added dos stub), still mingw generated exe rises only 2 alerts).

Comment: Many of the low-quality AV products are suspicious of anything that is not plain MSVC PE files with normal padding and layout.